# Error when clicking Column Name in Drag and Drop Datagridview

Tags: datagridview, vb.net-2010

I am having a problem in the drag & drop code. Whenever I click a `column name` my program will get an error.

This is the error I get by just clicking the column name:
[image]

I do get this error in my `Datagridview1_mousedown Event`

here is my code:

```
  Private Sub Datagridview1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Datagridview1.MouseDown

 SourceRowIndex = -1
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

            SourceRowIndex = Datagridview1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex
            Datagridview1.Rows(SourceRowIndex).Selected = True
            Datagridview1.Refresh()
            DoDragDrop(Datagridview1.Rows(SourceRowIndex), DragDropEffects.Move)

        End If
  End sub
```

I get the error in this part of the code:
`Datagridview1.Rows(SourceRowIndex).Selected = True`

Comment: Debug this and tell me the value of e.X and e.Y

Comment: OK, now we at least now that is a valid row. So what is the value of SourceRowIndex after that line ? does it match the rowindex of the hittest ?

Comment: Yes it matches. Then the error will show up after

Comment: that is very strange. Is Datagridview1.Rows.Count > SourceRowIndex ? Or in other words, is Datagridview1.Rows[SourceRowIncex) != null ?

Comment: I noticed, cliking the `column name` maintains the value of  `SourceRowIndex = -1`. So it gives me error. But clicking a `cell` in datagridview gives me a different value based on what index it is in

Comment: Now I understand. I missed this somehow in your question. When clicking on the headers from a datagridview it never returns a correct row, but always -1. This makes sense because the header of the datagridview is not a row but just titles. In other words, you cannot get the header row.